# How to pass jQuery value to PHP code?

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I'm trying to make an input table form to input new records of products in my MVC page, this is the View's code (I'm using MongoDB)

```
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++) {
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($modelItem, "[$i]name"); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextArea($modelItem, "[$i]description"); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($modelItem, "[$i]price"); ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

So, to make it an extendable input form, I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  addNewRow();
  function addNewRow() {
    var i = $("#listItem tbody tr").size();
    var arr = {};
    $("#listItem tbody tr:last").click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('addedRow') == false){
        arr.i = i;
        $("#ADD_PRICE_LIST_ROW").tmpl(arr).appendTo("#listItem tbody");
        addNewRow();
      }
      $(this).addClass('addedRow')
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

(The listItem tbody is the id of the table)
So what must I do to complete the function below?

```
<script id="ADD_PRICE_LIST_ROW" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <tr>
    ????
  </tr>
</script>
```

Sorry for the bad English =.=

Comment: A PHP script cannot process a client-side variable unless it has received it through an HTTP request. (`POST` or `GET`) Does this help point you in the right direction?

Comment: This question or a variant thereof gets asked every other day on SO. Perhaps, I'm wrong, but I'd imagine even a cursory search on Google would give you a virtual cornucopia of solutions all of which would tell you to use AJAX.

Comment: I'm not wrong, apparently. Even just literally searching for the question title gives you: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+pass+jQuery+value+to+PHP+code . StackOverflow should be your last resort, not your first.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use AJAX for this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/your/php.php',
    data: {
        post1: $('#element').val(),
        post2: $('#element2').text()
    },
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function() {
        $('#errors').text('Failed to get response from PHP');
    }
});
```

You can also use `$.post()` to do something similar if you don't need as many options:

```
$.post('/your/php.php', {
    post1: $('#element').val(),
    post2: $('#element2').text()
},
function(result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

You can place these inside something like something like `$('#button').on('click', function() { /* $.ajax() or $.post() */ });` or `$('#textbox1').on('keyup', function() { /* $.ajax() or $.post() */ });`.

Inside your PHP, you can do something like this to process it as any other POST:

```
if(isset($_POST['post1'])) {
    // $result = do stuff with $_POST['post1'];
    echo $result; // The jQuery will grab this as "result" and alert it...
}
```